# Axioms of seperation

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, separation-axioms

I am studying topological spaces, and I have seen that there are $3$ main axioms of separation: $\mathrm{T1}$,  Hausdorff and normal.

Now, between Hausdorff and normal there is a case where:
 given any closed set $F\in T$ and any point $x \in T$,  there is open set $O$ containing $F$ and a neighborhood $U$ containing $x$,  such that $U \cap O = \varnothing $. 
 This axiom of seperation is not the Hausdorff (stronger than Hausdorff) and not normal (weaker than normal).

My question is: is this indeed a different axiom?  Or can it be related via some theorem to one of the existing axioms?

Comment: Where are the periods, commas, etc.? I can't understand the question when written like this.

Comment: Yes it is indeed different. There are at least a dozen different separation axioms. If you want to delve into them I suggest Steen and Seebach, CounterExamples in Topology, 2nd ed.

Comment: Sorry added periods and commas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such a space is called (unimaginatively) [regular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_space). It is neither weaker nor stronger than Hausdorff. However, a regular $T_0$ space is automatically Hausdorff. A counterexample: a space with more than one point equipped with the trivial (indiscrete) topology is regular, but it's not Hausdorff.

Comment: A useful list is given here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_axiom

Comment: Thanks that was very helpful